# How to expand my PHP code to add more database fields?

Tags: php

I found a code php for updating database, but it's just for two field that's id and item. How about if I have 7 fields, that's id_admin, name, email, address, phonenumber, username, and password, and the table name is admin. This the code that I found.

```
 <?php
 error_reporting(0);
 include("db_config.php");

 // array for JSON response
 $response = array();

 if( isset($_POST['id'] ) && isset($_POST['item']) ) {
   $id=$_POST['id'];
   $item=$_POST['item'];

   $result = mysql_query("update myorder set item='$item' where id='$id' ")   or die(mysql_error());

   $row_count = mysql_affected_rows();

   if($row_count>0){
     $response["success"] = 1;
     $response["message"] = "Updated Sucessfully.";
    }
   else{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Failed To Update.";  
    }  
 // echoing JSON response
 echo json_encode($response); } ?>
```

Comment: You should always use parameterized queries.

Comment: remove single quotes from this where id=$id

Comment: what is that? i don't know much about php

Comment: @jothi, can you help me to edit that code?

Comment: update myorder set item='$item',name='value',......  where id='$id'

Comment: MYSQL is deprecated avoid use U should use mysqli or pdo

Comment: @jothi like this? update myorder set name='$name', email='$email', address='$address', phonenumber='$phonenumber', usename='$username', password='$passwoed' where id='$id_admin'

Comment: yeah your correct and try to follow my steps i posted below

Comment: Anything placed inside single quotes('') will be treated as string by php. If you need single quotes just try to concatenate them using ".".

Comment: @M.I. so it will be like this? udate myorder set name="$name", ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these lines :

```
   if( isset($_POST['id'] ) && isset($_POST['item']) ) {
   $id=$_POST['id'];
   $item=$_POST['item'];
   $result = mysql_query("update myorder set item='$item' where id='$id' ")   or die(mysql_error());
```

with these :

```
 if( isset($_POST['submit'] ) ) {
   $id=htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']);
   $item=htmlspecialchars($_POST['item']);
   $name=htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
   $email=htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
   //and so on... 
   $result = mysql_query("update myorder set item=$item, name=$name, email= $email ... where id=$id ")   or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Since you are a beginner, using mysql_* extension may seem to be easier for you. But i hope you will shift toward mysqli or pdo as sooner as possible..

Answer (score 0):

> Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.
>   Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

```
     <?php
      error_reporting(0);

     //db connection

     global $conn;

        $servername = "localhost";  //host name

        $username = "username"; //username

        $password = "password"; //password

        $mysql_database = "dbname"; //database name

    //mysqli prepared statement 

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

       mysqli_select_db($conn,$mysql_database) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");


      // array for JSON response
     $response = array();

     if( isset($_POST['id'] ) && isset($_POST['item']) ) {
       $id=$_POST['id'];
       $item=$_POST['item'];




     $stmt = $conn->prepare("update myorder set item=?,name=?,id_admin=?,email=?,address=?,phonenumber=? where id=? ");

                    $stmt->bind_param('ssissii',$item,$name,$id_admin,$email,$address,$phonenumber,$id);

                    The argument may be one of four types:

                    i - integer
                    d - double
                    s - string
                    b - BLOB
                    //change it by respectively 

                    $stmt->execute();

                    $row_count= $stmt->affected_rows;

                     if($row_count>0)
                     {
                 $response["success"] = 1;
                 $response["message"] = "Updated Sucessfully.";
                }
               else{
                $response["success"] = 0;
                $response["message"] = "Failed To Update.";  
                }  
             // echoing JSON response
             echo json_encode($response);


                    $stmt->close();
                     $conn->close();

             } 





        ?>
```

Comment: I saw this answer had a down vote, why would someone down vote it? (please explain when downvoting) seems the most correct answer in this post. As a beginner you should start this doing the right way, and prepared statements is the right way. mysql is outdated and for a reason, at least try mysqli.

Answer (score -1):

Always use parameterized queries when user value needs to be inserted in query.

Example:

```
$statement = $conn->prepare("update admin set name=?, email=?, address=?, phonenumber=?, username=?, password=? WHERE id_admin=?");
$statement->bind_param('ssssssi', $name, $email, $address, $phonenumber, $username, $password, $id_admin);
$statement->execute();
```